# On change, pass input value to php query

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I have a situation where I would use input element with google autocomplete place (which I restricted to cities) with no submit button. I would also run query on selected city and display results on the same page.

I'm stuck because I don't know how to pass selected city as parameter.
Situation is special because user would have drop down choice to select soon as he start typing something and he can select by clicking or by arrows+enter. So I know I should somehow reload page, with sending selected city in via GET method, when value of input field changes while being sure he finished choosing city.

I know this is much, but any hint or pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Use ajax, jquery and the change method of the input box ;)

Comment: Could I use $('#myTextbox').on('input', function() { }); to detect an if possible reload window with link which will have value of the text field appended to be grabbed from GET?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/K4656/